# Chaining tasks with delays

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a need to keep track of a task and potentially queue up another task after some delay so the way I'm thinking of doing it looks something like this:

```
private Task lastTask;

public void DoSomeTask()
{
    if (lastTask == null) 
    {
        lastTask = Task.FromResult(false);
    }
    lastTask = lastTask.ContinueWith(t => 
    {
        // do some task
    }).ContinueWith(t => Task.Delay(250).Wait());
}
```

My question is, if I do something like this, creating potentially long chains of tasks is will the older tasks be disposed or will they end up sticking around forever because the `ContinueWith` takes the last task as a parameter (so it's a closure). If so, how can I chain tasks while avoiding this problem?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you assume that `DoSomeTask()` will not be called in parallel?

Comment: @YacoubMassad It wouldn't affect the specific questions he's asking about even if he were.

Comment: Any chance you can use `async`/`await`? The code will be way simple and easier to reason about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Task.Delay(250).Wait()
```

You *know* you're doing something wrong when you use `Wait` in code you're trying to make asynchronous. That's one wasted thread doing nothing.

The following would be much better:

```
lastTask = lastTask.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    // do some task
}).ContinueWith(t => Task.Delay(250)).Unwrap();
```

`ContinueWith` returns a `Task<Task>`, and the `Unwrap` call turns that into a `Task` which will complete when the *inner* task does.

Now, to answer your question, let's take a look at what the compiler generates:

```
public void DoSomeTask()
{
    if (this.lastTask == null)
        this.lastTask = (Task) Task.FromResult<bool>(false);
    // ISSUE: method pointer
    // ISSUE: method pointer
    this.lastTask = this.lastTask
    .ContinueWith(
        Program.<>c.<>9__2_0
        ?? (Program.<>c.<>9__2_0 = new Action<Task>((object) Program.<>c.<>9, __methodptr(<DoSomeTask>b__2_0))))
    .ContinueWith<Task>(
        Program.<>c.<>9__2_1
        ?? (Program.<>c.<>9__2_1 = new Func<Task, Task>((object) Program.<>c.<>9, __methodptr(<DoSomeTask>b__2_1))))
    .Unwrap();
}

[CompilerGenerated]
[Serializable]
private sealed class <>c
{
    public static readonly Program.<>c <>9;
    public static Action<Task> <>9__2_0;
    public static Func<Task, Task> <>9__2_1;

    static <>c()
    {
        Program.<>c.<>9 = new Program.<>c();
    }

    public <>c()
    {
        base.\u002Ector();
    }

    internal void <DoSomeTask>b__2_0(Task t)
    {
    }

    internal Task <DoSomeTask>b__2_1(Task t)
    {
        return Task.Delay(250);
    }
}
```

This was decompiled with dotPeek in *"show me all the guts"* mode.

Look at this part:

```
.ContinueWith<Task>(
    Program.<>c.<>9__2_1
    ?? (Program.<>c.<>9__2_1 = new Func<Task, Task>((object) Program.<>c.<>9, __methodptr(<DoSomeTask>b__2_1))))
```

The `ContinueWith` function is given a singleton delegate. So, there's no closing over any variable there.

Now, there's this function:

```
internal Task <DoSomeTask>b__2_1(Task t)
{
    return Task.Delay(250);
}
```

The `t` here is a reference to the previous task. Notice something? It's never used. The JIT will mark this local as being unreachable, and the GC will be able to clean it. With optimizations enabled, the JIT will aggressively mark locals that are eligible for collection, even to the point that an instance method can be executing *while* the instance is being collected by the GC, if said instance method doesn't reference `this` in the code left to execute.

Now, one last thing, there's the [`m_parent`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,9bcf4ac1b708d344,references) field in the `Task` class, which is not good for your scenario. But as long as you're not using `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent` you should be fine. You could always add the `DenyChildAttach` flag for extra safety and self-documentation.

Here's the [function which deals with that](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,030247360ff2c4b9,references):

```
internal static Task InternalCurrentIfAttached(TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
{
    return (creationOptions & TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent) != 0 ? InternalCurrent : null;
}
```

So, you should be safe here. If you want to be *sure*, run a memory profiler on a long chain, and see for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

> if I do something like this, creating potentially long chains of tasks is will the older tasks be disposed

Tasks do not require explicit disposal, as they don't contain unmanaged resources.

> will they end up sticking around forever because the ContinueWith takes the last task as a parameter (so it's a closure)

It's *not* a closure.  A closure is an anonymous method using a variable *from outside the scope of that anonymous method* in its body.  You're not doing that, so you're not closing over it.  Each `Task` does however have a field where it keeps track of its parent, so the managed `Task` object will still be accessible if you're using this pattern.

Comment: The parent should be null in his scenario, as long as he avoids `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [source code of the ContinuationTaskFromTask class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs). It has the following code:

```
internal override void InnerInvoke()
{
    // Get and null out the antecedent.  This is crucial to avoid a memory
    // leak with long chains of continuations.
    var antecedent = m_antecedent;
    Contract.Assert(antecedent != null, 
        "No antecedent was set for the ContinuationTaskFromTask.");
    m_antecedent = null;
```

`m_antecedent` is the field that holds a reference to the antecedent ask. The developers here explicitly set it to `null` (after it is no longer needed) to make sure that there is no memory leak with long chains of continuations, which I guess is your concern.